# SetThreadAffinityMask() not seeming to take effect more than once

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to set the affinity of my thread to a certain mask each time I run a thread by pressing a button. It will work the first time I do it after opening the window, but not after that. However, my `OutputDebugString` code produces output that suggests it has been changed. I've tried using `CloseHandle()` but that didn't seem to have an effect. Is there something else it could be?

```
void CSMPDemoDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // Start thread
    DWORD_PTR affinityMask = (static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(1) << NumberOfCores ) - 1;

    HANDLE WorkThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, WorkThread, &tp, 0, NULL);
    DWORD_PTR z = SetThreadAffinityMask(WorkThreadHandle, affinityMask);

    if (z!=0) {
        char bb[100];
        sprintf_s(bb, 100, "Affinity changed from %d to %d", z, affinityMask);
        OutputDebugString(bb);
    }
}
```

Comment: What difference are you expecting to see? What are you seeing?

Comment: By the way, you are setting the mask to the same value each time, so how do you expect it to CHANGE things?

Comment: I'm writing a benchmarking program that measures performance when running routines using different numbers of cores. So it will run it on 1, then 2, then 4 cores etc. However, when I run on 1 core it jumps between cores and causes my graphs to be a bit hard to read. I'm trying to set the affinity so that it runs on the cores I want it to, producing a nicer graph. (I understand that setting affinity will most likely reduce performance, that is OK). NumberOfCores is a variable that changes elsewhere, just an example of my code, sorry I should have made that clear.

Comment: Then, please explain what happens/how it is different from what you expect.

Comment: Each time I press the button, a thread should start (with the affinity I set). Running the thread once, I can see in the task manager (and my graphs) that its being run on the cores I've chosen, because the corresponding graphs will shoot up to ~100%. But when I change settings in the program and press the button again, it should run on different cores. But it runs on the same cores as before, and not the newly set ones. So basically it won't let me set the affinity again once I've set it once.

Comment: To me, it looks like you are allowing the thread to run on any core up to NumberOfCores here - was that your intention?

Comment: Yes, it's working how I want once, so if I set 4 it runs on 0,1,2,3. I just can't set it again once its been set

Answer (score 3):

So, you want something like this:

```
 static count = 0;
 DWORD_PTR affinityMask = (static_cast<DWORD_PTR>(1) << NumberOfCores ) - 1;
 affinityMask <<= ((count * numberOfCores)  % totalCores);
```

That means that it will run on the next set of cores in the group, so if you run on, say 4 cores, the first tiem, it will run on cores 0..3, then 4..7, then 8..11.

It does assume that `totalCores` is a multiple of `numberofCores`, so if you have 16 cores and `numberOfCores = 3`, you'll get weird results.